# How to model a bloom filter in Scala

Tags: scala, data-structures, functional-programming, case-class, bloom-filter

I am trying to model a bloom filter in Scala. The logic itself is actually pretty straightforward, but I'm struggling to figure out how to use Scala's data structures adequately to make nice, idiomatic and functional.

My problem is this: if I use a case class, I need the constructor to generate the hash functions and the bits array that will store the actual bloom filter's data.
But then, in a method like "add" that will change the contents of the bits array, I need to return a new bloom filter instead of mutating the contents of the existing one in order for my method to be referentially transparent.

Unfortunately I can't construct a new bloom filter, because I don't want the new one to re-create a new bits array and new hash functions, and I also can't pass it the existing ones because neither the bits array nor the hash functions are part of the bloom filter case class.

So how am I supposed to model this in Scala?

Comment: I would think you'd want to keep the bit-array `private` to the instance, creating a new one with each `add`, and the hash functions `private` to the companion object. (But that's just off the top of my head.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ Modified to use `BitSet`, following comment ]

This is an outline of how it might work.

```
trait HashFunctions[T] {
  def apply(value: T): BitSet
}

object Bloom {
  class BloomFactory[T](hash: HashFunctions[T]) {
    case class Bloom(flags: BitSet) {
      def add(value: T): Bloom =
        Bloom(flags union hash(value))
      def test(value: T): Boolean =
        hash(value).subsetOf(flags)
    }
  }

  def apply[T](): BloomFactory[T]#Bloom = new BloomFactory(DefaultHashFunctions[T]).Bloom(BitSet.empty)
}
```

Note that this does create a new `Bloom` each time you add a value, but this makes the class immutable which is a good idea. The hash functions are created in the companion object so that this does not happen each time you `add` to the filter.

Clearly this can be made significantly more efficient in both speed and memory usage.

Comment: Maybe [`BitSet`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/BitSet.html) instead of `Set[Int]` ?

Comment: In a naive approach, I've used an `Array[Boolean]`, and I toggle the booleans at the indexes given by my hash functions @AlexanderAzarov. But I've looked at other implementations and they're using BitSet indeed.
What would be the benefit of using a BitSet (or Set[Int])?

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov Thanks, I've modified to code to use `BitSet`, which is likely to be faster for both add and updated.